# Telerik MVC website with batch editing grid prevent unsaved changes when window is closed

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, jquery, telerik-mvc

I have a webpage in ASP.Net MVC3 using Razor engine.I am using Telerik MVC Grid batch editing within this page. Using Telerik's inbuilt onDataBinding event I can force the user to save his changes if he tries to go to the next page. But when the user closes the browser window or clicks on the menu buttons on the header and if there are unsaved changes in the grid he is not prompted to save those. How can I handle this?? Please help. I would like to give the user a prompt which tells him he has unsaved changes.

Thanks,
SDD

Answer (score 0):

You could capture the browser closed event and check if your Telerik grid has any unsaved changes by calling the `.hasChanges()` method.

```
function wireUpEvents() {

  // Check for grid changes before page unload
  window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        var grid = $("#MyGrid").data('tGrid');
        if (grid.hasChanges()) {
            if (!confirm('You are going to lose any unsaved changes. Are you sure?')) {
                e.preventDefault();
       }
    }
  }
}

// Wire up the events as soon as the DOM is ready
$(document).ready(function() {
  wireUpEvents();  
});
```

Comment: @sdd Did this help you at all?